Counter in custom sequence using JK flip-flops
I need a counter that displays a custom number sequence instead of counting up or down.
I know I'm gonna need 3 JKs, meaning 2 ICs with 2 flip-flops. a few logic gates, but I don't really get how I should start the project. I thought of using one flip-flop in toggle mode and going like 0-1-0-1, then I realized the opposite of that is what I'm going to need for one of the k inputs in one of the bits.
So I can use the inverse of the exit of this one to control the one I need. then I need logic based on the first input to go to the next. I know how to use a truth table and a Karnaugh map to get an expression and implement it, I just don't know how to make it change into the next.
I need a few more steps described in more detail. Idk
So, the questions are, how should I go from one FF to the next, where is my main signal, can I set the flip-flop values to 110 (6) before the program starts? I really don't know what to do there, with 2 more days, I'm sure I'd figure it out, but I can't do it before it's due
I'm trying to make the first one start at 6

I would recommend starting by drawing a state transition table after identifying the 4 binary states.   Identify how many input bits for the states based on values present in decimal.  Then split the corresponding outputs into separate outputs in the table as columns, you should have 4 rows and 2 columns per row for binary state and next state respectively and then 3 columns for the binary outputs from each desired state output.    You will need to identify the type of flip flop you need.  Are you creating this in schematic capture or HDL code?   Also since this is sequential you need a clock.

The requirement is to generate four states 6-2-3-7 in that order with a repeating cycle of length 4. To design a counter for those values it helps to look at the numbers in binary format. Simplest solution s usually best.



N
binary
reduced
M




6
110
1 0
2


2
010
0 0
0


3
011
0 1
1


7
111
1 1
3



Where it is now obvious that bit 1 is always one! So we can fix that.
Now you only need two JK flip flops and to design the logic for it to generate 2-0-1-3 in that order. That way there are no other invalid states to worry about. It would be more challenging if there was a cycle of 5 states.

It was quite similar to the solution I did implement in the end. Thanks for the help. I noticed that the implementation of the solution is where I had the most difficulty, as it happens, it didn't work as expected, but I don't know how to make it work now. The theory is solid, the logic works really well, it's just the MSB receiving the LSB and the LSB receiving the inverted MSB. It was really fun to get there. I did it alone, in the end. I wish I knew where the problem is, I think it's in the currents and voltages, not the logic. It's up to experience now. I'm gonna redo it later. Thank you!
